# How can I format DisplayFormula Cell into TraditionalForm when export as HTML

Tags: formatting

[image]

This example is in `DisplayFormula` cell.

```
cellExpression=Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{RowBox[{SuperscriptBox["f","\[Prime]",MultilineFunction->None],RowBox[{"(","x",")"}]}],"=",RowBox[{RowBox[{"sin","",FractionBox["1","x"]}],"-",RowBox[{FractionBox["1","x"],"cos",FractionBox["1","x"],RowBox[{"(",RowBox[{"x","!=","0"}],")"}]}]}]}]],"DisplayFormulaNumbered"];CellPrint@cellExpression
```

How can I format them to the appearance like the following in batch.

I set `FontSize->Times`, and `Italic` for $\color{Green}{f'(x)}$, $x$ seperately, but not so easy for too many `InlineFormula`/`DisplayFormula/...` cells by hand.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

$$\begin{align*}\color{blue}{f'(x)}=\sin  \frac{1}{\color{red}{x}}-\frac{1}{\color{red}{x}}\cos\frac{1}{\color{red}{x}}(\color{red}{x}\neq 0)\tag{1}\end{align*}$$

When I export notebook as html, the formulas are rasterized to image which not in `TraditionalForm` which shown above as that I setted by hand.

[sample typesetting, inline formulas are images, I'm thinking that how to make them more beautiful and more traditional formal. Most of them are typed into Mathematica by hand](http://hypergroups.blog.163.com/blog/static/2209751202013615105112837/)

As you'll see that some single `f`s are Times Italic, they are good shown, but in `DisplayFormula` they are not.

#### Edit:

Mike Honeychurch's example

[image]

My Setting(related?):

[image]

#### ------------Note:

I've tried Mike's method, however failed, how about yours.

I'm on *Windows* and *Mathemtaica* 9.

Comment: @Nasser well, good to know about that, I'll consider it after I can play around converting Notebook To Latex well.

Answer (score 2):

Your underlying box structure is not quite right. You need to add `FormBox`es and `TextData`. e.g.

```
cellExpression = 
  Cell[TextData[
    Cell[BoxData[
      FormBox[RowBox[{RowBox[{SuperscriptBox["f", "\[Prime]", 
            MultilineFunction -> None], RowBox[{"(", "x", ")"}]}], 
         "=", RowBox[{RowBox[{"sin", "", FractionBox["1", "x"]}], "-",
            RowBox[{FractionBox["1", "x"], "cos", 
             FractionBox["1", "x"], 
             RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"x", "\[NotEqual]", "0"}], 
               ")"}]}]}]}], TraditionalForm]],
     FormatType -> "TraditionalForm"]
    ], "DisplayFormulaNumbered"];
CellPrint@cellExpression
```

The correct form can be determined by building these equations in a e.g. text cell, starting with the new cell and then pressing control 9.

**Edit**

pasted is the gif image that Mathematica generates when you save the code and generated cell above as HTML.

[image]

I did this with V8 on Mac 10.6.8

Comment: When I saved your sample as .html, they're also not traditional form. How about in yours?

Comment: yep they are traditional form. see edit.

Comment: I donot know why I can't follow your effect, only `Output` Cell and `InlineFormula` cell can become `TraditionalForm`.

Comment: What version & platform are you using and what stylesheet are you using? Have you modified the stylesheet?

Comment: mathematica 9, windows 8,  Default Stylesheet and Styled stylesheets.

Comment: I've tried one stylesheet---`JournalArticle`, and then I'm successful, How to make self-defined stylesheet work like that.

Comment: I create a DisplayFormula, why there is no default `FormatType->"TraditionalForm"`, and `"FormBox"...=TraditionalForm`, how to auto generate is when create a DisplayFormula, and type in Formulas.